# Insert a symbol in table "outside" the respective column? (Right of right-aligned entries)

Tags: tables, alignment

I wondered whether I could insert a * next to special values in a table. All values are right aligned to make them easily comparable. If I just type the * after an entry, the respective entry will no longer be in line with the others. Can I somehow place the *-symbol "outside the column"?

Edit: Some sample code, as requested by leandriis:

```
\begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrr}
   sample &\multicolumn{3}{c}{As [mg/kg]} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Fe [g/kg]} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Mn [mg/kg]} \\
 ID & digestion & HCl & PO4 & digestion & HCl & PO4 & digestion & HCl & PO4 \\

 \hline
G-01 & 5.60 & 0.52 & 0.79 & 232.35 & 1.64 & 0.36 & 20.89 & 193.06 & 138.13 \\ 
  GL-S1 & 1.00 & 0.52 & 0.41 & 5.31 & 1.68 & 0.32 & 139.77 & 216.07 & 98.11 \\

  GL-S2 & 1.07 & 0.49 & 0.58* & 5.58 & 1.63 & 0.34* & 124.60 & 191.87 & 138.28 \\

  GL-S3 & 1.20 & 0.55 & 0.73 & 6.34 & 1.81 & 0.34 & 120.96 & 198.15 & 127.67
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: yes, e.g. with \rlap, siunitx has options for this too.

Comment: Could you please add some example code for others to work with? Apart from that, the `siunitx` package and its `S` type columns might be useful given thatn "vaules"  refers to numerical values.

Comment: Thanks for adding the example code. I have updated my answer to demonstrate how to apply the `siunitx` package (as well as some other changes)  to your table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestion is a huge improvement to my table!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an updated answer on how to use the `siunitx` package on your example table. I have also used the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package and the `\ce` command from the `mhchem` package in order to typeset PO4. (If this refers to the phosphate anion, you might want to add the charge as well.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l
                S[table-format=1.2]
                S[table-format=1.2]
                S[table-format=1.2,table-space-text-post = {*}]
                S[table-format=3.2]
                S[table-format=1.2]
                S[table-format=1.2,table-space-text-post = {*}]
                S[table-format=3.2]
                S[table-format=3.2]
                S[table-format=3.2]
                }
   sample &\multicolumn{3}{c}{As [\si{\mg\per \kg}]} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Fe [\si{\g \per \kg}]} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Mn [\si{\mg \per \kg}]} \\ 
   \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
 ID & {digestion} & {HCl} & \ce{PO4} & {digestion} & {HCl} & \ce{PO4} & {digestion} & {HCl} & \ce{PO4} \\
\midrule
G-01 & 5.60 & 0.52 & 0.79 & 232.35 & 1.64 & 0.36 & 20.89 & 193.06 & 138.13 \\ 
  GL-S1 & 1.00 & 0.52 & 0.41 & 5.31 & 1.68 & 0.32 & 139.77 & 216.07 & 98.11 \\

  GL-S2 & 1.07 & 0.49 & 0.58* & 5.58 & 1.63 & 0.34* & 124.60 & 191.87 & 138.28 \\

  GL-S3 & 1.20 & 0.55 & 0.73 & 6.34 & 1.81 & 0.34 & 120.96 & 198.15 & 127.67
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Original answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.3,table-space-text-post = {*}]}
left aligned text & 1.24 \\
more text         & 1.343* \\
more text & 21.24* \\
more text         & 21.343 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\sisetup{table-align-text-post    = false}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.3,table-space-text-post = {*}]}
left aligned text & 1.24 \\
more text         & 1.343* \\
more text & 21.24* \\
more text         & 21.343 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]